# icu4 anc freetype

Tags: android, icu, freetype

I want to know what is the difference between ICU4 and freetype.
Many application or libs uses either of these two like webkit. what is the relation between these two? which one is better.

Answer (score 0):

They are totally different libraries with totally different purposes.

The first blurb on [ICU's](http://site.icu-project.org/) page;

> ICU is a mature, widely used set of C/C++ and Java libraries providing Unicode and Globalization support for software applications. ICU is widely portable and gives applications the same results on all platforms and between C/C++ and Java software.

The first blurb on [FreeType's](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/index.html) page:

> FreeType 2 is a software font engine that is designed to be small, efficient, highly customizable, and portable while capable of producing high-quality output (glyph images). It can be used in graphics libraries, display servers, font conversion tools, text image generation tools, and many other products as well.
>
> Note that FreeType 2 is a font service and doesn't provide APIs to
>   perform higher-level features like text layout or graphics processing
>   (e.g., colored text rendering, ‘hollowing’, etc.). However, it greatly
>   simplifies these tasks by providing a simple, easy to use, and uniform
>   interface to access the content of font files.